# Problem retrieving a file that is outside root directory

Tags: html

I have a problem retrieving a flash file that is outside of the root directory.

What I have are 5 websites that use the same flash file, so I created a folder outside (one level up) of the 5 domains on my server. In the folder I have my flash file.

I am using the relative path below, but no worky worky.

"../resources/helpful_info.swf"

If I move the resource file and website files under a single domain it works fine. So, it seems I have a problem when I use a relative path and jump outside the domain to search for a file.

I don't want to use absolute path because files and paths change too much here.

Any ideas? I need it to worky worky
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Your path does not make sense.

Relative paths are interpreted by the *client*, and they're used to compose a path within your domain.
You cannot use a relative path to tell the client to fetch a file outside the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You also cannot reference outside your site at server side.  Think security.

I see 2 fast solutions:
1) Create a new domain put the flash there.  Other security problems like cross site scripting might occur.
2) Make a copy of the flash for all 5 domains.  It is it update often create a script to copy it to every domain.